# Function not get called from dynamically created html code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'am changing the html code from javascript and want to call same function from created "div"s. but it is not called.

As you can see 'html' which is formed after function invoke also has class="screen" but created 'div's doesn't support it.

```js
var i;
var clear = 2;
$("#container").click(function() {
  var clickid = $(this).attr('id');
  var left = document.getElementById(clickid).offsetLeft;
  var top = document.getElementById(clickid).offsetTop;
  var height = document.getElementById(clickid).offsetHeight;
  var width = document.getElementById(clickid).offsetWidth;
  var x = document.getElementById(clickid).value;
  orient = prompt("vertical or horizontal ?");
  numdiv = prompt("How many divisions should be created ?");
  var divsper = [];
  var html = "";
  for (i = 0; i < numdiv; i++) {
    per = prompt("Percentage of " + (i + 1) + "th division ?");
    divsper.push(per);
  }
  if (orient == "vertical") {
    for (i = 0; i < numdiv; i++) {
      l = Math.floor(left + ((i * divsper[i] * width) / 100));
      w = Math.floor((divsper[i] * width) / 100);
      html = html + "<div id=" + clickid + " class=\"screen\" style=\"float:left; top:" + (top) + "px; left:" + (l) + "px; height:" + (height - clear) + "px; width:" + (w - clear) + "px; border:1px solid black;\"></div>"
    }
    document.getElementById(clickid).outerHTML = html;
    //document.getElementById(clickid).unwrap();
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {}

#container {
  background-color: pink;
  top=0%;
  left=0%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="screen">
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which explains how to properly use Stack Snippets.

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**.

Comment: also .click wont work with newly created elements. use .on() method of jquery to bind events

Comment: @Andreas yeah i will do it with class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace '$("#container").click(function() {' this line with '$("html").on('click', '[id*=container]', function() {'.
It will work for you.

```js
var i;
var clear = 2;
$("html").on('click', '[id*=container]', function() {
  var clickid = $(this).attr('id');
  var left = this.offsetLeft;
  var top = this.offsetTop;
  var height = this.offsetHeight;
  var width = this.offsetWidth;
  var x = this.value;
  orient = prompt("vertical or horizontal ?");
  numdiv = prompt("How many divisions should be created ?");
  var divsper = [];
  var html = "";
  for (i = 0; i < numdiv; i++) {
    per = prompt("Percentage of " + (i + 1) + "th division ?");
    divsper.push(per);
  }
  if (orient == "vertical") {
    for (i = 0; i < numdiv; i++) {
      l = Math.floor(left + ((i * divsper[i] * width) / 100));
      w = Math.floor((divsper[i] * width) / 100);
      html = html + "<div id=" + clickid + (i + 1) + " class=\"screen\" style=\"float:left; top:" + (top) + "px; left:" + (l) + "px; height:" + (height - clear) + "px; width:" + (w - clear) + "px; border:1px solid black;\"></div>"
    }
    this.outerHTML = html;
    //this.unwrap();
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {}

#container {
  background-color: pink;
  top=0%;
  left=0%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="screen">
</div>
```

Comment: It worked. But I want the split to be happen on the <div> which I clicked. well here its happening on the first div it gets with the ID.

Comment: all newly created div's will have class=screen and id's as container1,container2,container11,.. etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using $('#container').on('click') instead. Dynamically generated html event handling is slightly different.